# Performance of eval() with large scripts

Tags: javascript, eval

I'm trying out [script-loader](https://github.com/webpack/script-loader) as a way to add pre-built scripts to my Webpack bundle. So far it has been working well, but while looking at the code I noticed that it bundles scripts as a string and then executes them by calling `eval()`.

I'm adding a couple of relatively large scripts, and although I personally can't notice any performance issues while loading the page, I'm worried that there could be a significant hit in performance on less powerful devices.

Does this seem like a bad idea or would it not differ significantly from just executing the scripts directly without `eval()`?

Comment: Usually `eval` has no extra performance hit, but I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "*just executing the scripts directly*"? If they are dynamically bundled to strings, you cannot really avoid `eval`.

Comment: @Bergi what I mean is that if I wasn't using Webpack I could just concatenate the scripts into a single file and there would be no need for `eval()`. I would lose other benefits of Webpack if I did this though.